# Rewrite a path with htaccess to different urls, based on calling path

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I've been struggling to redirect to two different urls (files) based on what is in the path of the calling url, ie:

example.com/rh/xxxxx/ -> user.php?a=xxxxx

example.com/rh/xxxxx/yyyyy/ -> record.php?a=xxxxx&b=yyyyy

Here's what I have so far, and it's not working.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/rh/[^/]*/[^/]*/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/rh/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ record.php?a=$1&b=$2 [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/rh/[^/]*/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/rh/([^/]*)/?$ user.php?a=$1 [L,NC]
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 - No go. Cleared the browser and DNS caches, but got a 404 error. If I remove the rh/ then I get  the user.php page each time. Odd.

Comment: Could you please do mention paths of your htaccess and php files once? Looks like 404 means file is not found by apache

Comment: the 'rh' directory is one level deep from the html root: /rh/. The htaccess file would be here: /rh/.htaccess. The files would be here: /rh/recored.php and /rh/user.php.

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples please try following .htaccess rules file. Please make sure to keep your .htaccess rules files along with `record.php` and `user.php`.

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
##Rewrite rule for example.com/rh/xxxxx/yyyyy/ -> record.php?a=xxxxx&b=yyyyy
RewriteRule ^rh/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ record.php?a=$1&b=$2 [L,NC]

##Rewrite rule for example.com/rh/xxxxx/ -> user.php?a=xxxxx
RewriteRule ^rh/([^/]*)/?$ user.php?a=$1 [L,NC]
```